# Tree identification - Oregon

Tags: species-identification, trees

[image][image][image][image]A bit west of Portland. It doesn't look native to me, and we didn't plant it. This is the first year it flowered, so I decided to see if I can get it identified. If it matters, the flowers are aromatic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a Privet (Genus *Ligustrum*). It appears to be *Ligustrum vulgare* which is known as Common Privet, or sometimes European Privet.

It is a common woodland understorey shrub in Europe, often planted as garden hedging in urban areas as it is semi-deciduous and responds well to repeated pruning. You could never really call it a tree, it is a shrub species.

The white flowers as you say are quite fragrant and pleasant. They develop into shiny black/dark purple berries.

Comment: I would normally add some photos of my own, but yours are so good they show all the characteristic features very well.